# Facing PHP Fatal error occurred while uploading to Frankfurt bucket with php version 7

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3

```
PHP Fatal error occurred: Uncaught Guzzle\Service\Exception\ValidationException: Validation errors:  
 [Key] is a required string in lib/amazon/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php:357  
 Stack trace:  
 #0 /lib/amazon/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php(236): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->validate()  
 #1 /lib/amazon/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(205): Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand->prepare()  
 #2 /lib/amazon/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(136): Guzzle\Service\Client->prepareCommand(Object(Aws\S3\Command\S3Command))  
 #3 /lib/amazon/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/Abst in /lib/amazon/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php on line 357.
```

I am performing chunk upload to amazon s3.This issue does not occur in other buckets while uploading. I searched but not get proper solution for this issue.
can anyone help me to resolve this issue?